# Git Undo last few pushes after a pull request merge, keeping the merge

Tags: git, github, merge

I had pushed a fix commit directly to master, which is against purity standards. We usually have pull requests merges.

Then I git pulled everything and switched to feature branch (fb).
Then after realizing impurity, I checked out master, reverted the direct push, and did a push -f origin

So master started looking good again. 
However, since the pull request was created before, when I merge my pull request to master, I again see the bad commit that was directly done (read from bottom up):

```
- commit 4 - Merge pull request xyz commit 3 from fb
- commit 3 - Some message  
- commit 2 - Revert "commit 1 - Some message" 
- commit 1 - Some message // (direct commit to master) 
- commit 0 previous - last known good commit
```

Basically, I want to get rid of in between things and want nothing to exist between:

```
- commit 4 - Merge pull request xyz commit 3 from fb 
- commit 0 previous - last known good commit
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do a rebase:

```
git rebase --interactive commit_4^
```

then delete lines about commits you don't want to keep.

Keep in mind you will loose them ... well, you can still get them back (using reflog), but they won't exist in your log history anymore.

This is also not advised when other people are using your master, because it will create a diverged history. They will need to rebase their master against the new one you will push force.